# NDepend: how to limit JustMyCode to the methods used by x?

Tags: ndepend

The [official documentation](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/cqlinq-syntax#NotMyCode) explains how to limit JustMyCode by exclusion using notmycode

```
notmycode from m in Methods where
  m.SourceFileDeclAvailable && 
  m.SourceDecls.First().SourceFile.FileName.ToLower().EndsWith(".designer.cs")
select m
```

I'd like to limit JustMyCode to **only** the methods returned by this query

```
from m in Methods 
let depth0 = m.DepthOfIsUsedBy("InsertMuk(Int32,Int32,BetCoupon,Boolean,Boolean,Boolean,DateTime&,Boolean)")
where depth0  >= 0 orderby depth0
select new { m, depth0 }
```

Will it redefine the codebase for all the other queries?

Comment: I've found a solution which seems to work, but before posting it I'm waiting in case of a better one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should work, assuming you disable all other `notmycode` queries and also that you provide `Namespace.ClassName` in the string:

```
notmycode
let methodsUsed =  Methods.Where(m1 => m1.DepthOfIsUsedBy("Namespace.ClassName.InsertMuk(Int32,Int32,BetCoupon,Boolean,Boolean,Boolean,DateTime&,Boolean)") >= 0)
from m in Methods.Except(methodsUsed )
select m
```